# Embedding Files into a pdf document and auto extracting them

Tags: windows-7, pdf

Is there any way to embed some files into a pdf, and pdf file extracts them into a directory at its start up and pass a command line for them?

Comment: Why would you do this? - Are you trying to pass a Virus to some one?

Comment: exe files can not embed or run from pdf files, so no virus

Answer (score 1):

No, you can add Files with Acrobat Pro to a so called Portfolio-PDF but they won't Autoextract.